# Runway argument

Tags: tables, sharelatex, syntax

I am unable to insert the tables in my Latex document. The following is the error message

```
"{\clearpage \thispagestyle {empty}\begin {landscape}\centering \begin \ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \afterpage.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.123     \include{C-chapter5}

I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file"
```

---

```
\afterpage{%
    \clearpage% Flush earlier floats (otherwise order might not be correct)
   \thispagestyle{empty}% empty page style (?)
   \begin{landscape}% Landscape page
   \centering % Center table
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{Natural frequency change patterns of Shear beam as the number of modes increases from n = 1 to n = 5 for axial compression load = $1.6*10^5$, $1.6*10^8$ N for stiffness increment value of $10^{7}$ $\frac{N}{m}$}
\label{tab:5.230}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{} & \multicolumn{8}{c|}{\textbf{Change in Natural Frequency}} \\ \hline
\textbf{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 1.5}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 2}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 2.5}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 3}} \\ \hline
\textbf{Mode No} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -1.6*10\textasciicircum{}5\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -1.6*10\textasciicircum{}8\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -1.6*10\textasciicircum{}5\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -1.6*10\textasciicircum{}8\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -1.6*10\textasciicircum{}5\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -1.6*10\textasciicircum{}8\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -1.6*10\textasciicircum{}5\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -1.6*10\textasciicircum{}8\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
1 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
2 & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase \\ \hline
3 & decrease & decrease & decrease & decrease & decrease & decrease & decrease & decrease \\ \hline
4 & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase \\ \hline
5 & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{Natural frequency change patterns of Shear beam as the number of modes increases from n = 1 to n = 5 for axial compression load = $2.4*10^5$, $2.4*10^8$ N for stiffness increment value of $10^{7}$ $\frac{N}{m}$}
\label{tab:5.231}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{} & \multicolumn{8}{c|}{\textbf{Change in Natural Frequency}} \\ \hline
\textbf{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 1.5}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 2}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 2.5}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 3}} \\ \hline
\textbf{Mode No} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -2.4*10\textasciicircum{}5\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -2.4*10\textasciicircum{}8\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -2.4*10\textasciicircum{}5\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -2.4*10\textasciicircum{}8\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -2.4*10\textasciicircum{}5\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -2.4*10\textasciicircum{}8\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -2.4*10\textasciicircum{}5\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -2.4*10\textasciicircum{}8\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
1 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
2 & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase \\ \hline
3 & decrease & decrease & decrease & decrease & decrease & decrease & decrease & decrease \\ \hline
4 & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase \\ \hline
5 & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table
            \end{landscape}
   \clearpage% Flush page
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% ksp=1e9 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\afterpage{%
    \clearpage% Flush earlier floats (otherwise order might not be correct)
   \thispagestyle{empty}% empty page style (?)
   \begin{landscape}% Landscape page
       \centering % Center table
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{Natural frequency change patterns of Shear beam as the number of modes increases from n = 1 to n = 5 for axial compression load = 0 N for stiffness increment value of $10^{9}$ $\frac{N}{m}$}
\label{tab:5.232}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{} & \multicolumn{8}{c|}{\textbf{Change in Natural Frequency}} \\ \hline
\textbf{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 1.5}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 2}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 2.5}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 3}} \\ \hline
\textbf{Mode No} & \textbf{P = 0} & \textbf{P = 0} & \textbf{P = 0} & \textbf{P = 0} & \textbf{P = 0} & \textbf{P = 0} & \textbf{P = 0} & \textbf{P = 0} \\ \hline
1 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
2 & increase & increase & constant & constant & constant & constant & constant & constant \\ \hline
3 & decrease & decrease & constant & constant & constant & constant & constant & constant \\ \hline
4 & constant & constant & constant & constant & constant & constant & constant & constant \\ \hline
5 & increase & increase & constant & constant & constant & constant & constant & constant \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{Natural frequency change patterns of Shear beam as the number of modes increases from n = 1 to n = 5 for axial compression load = $0.8*10^5$, $0.8*10^8$ N for stiffness increment value of $10^{9}$ $\frac{N}{m}$}
\label{tab:5.233}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{} & \multicolumn{8}{c|}{\textbf{Change in Natural Frequency}} \\ \hline
\textbf{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 1.5}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 2}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 2.5}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 3}} \\ \hline
\textbf{Mode No} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -0.8*10\textasciicircum{}5\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -0.8*10\textasciicircum{}8\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -0.8*10\textasciicircum{}5\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -0.8*10\textasciicircum{}8\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -0.8*10\textasciicircum{}5\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -0.8*10\textasciicircum{}8\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -0.8*10\textasciicircum{}5\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -0.8*10\textasciicircum{}8\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
1 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
2 & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase \\ \hline
3 & decrease & decrease & decrease & decrease & decrease & decrease & decrease & decrease \\ \hline
4 & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & constant & increase \\ \hline
5 & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}       
            \end{landscape}
   \clearpage% Flush page
}
\afterpage{%
    \clearpage% Flush earlier floats (otherwise order might not be correct)
   \thispagestyle{empty}% empty page style (?)
   \begin{landscape}% Landscape page
       \centering % Center table
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{Natural frequency change patterns of Shear beam as the number of modes increases from n = 1 to n = 5 for axial compression load = $1.6*10^5$, $1.6*10^8$ N for stiffness increment value of $10^{9}$ $\frac{N}{m}$}
\label{tab:5.234}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{} & \multicolumn{8}{c|}{\textbf{Change in Natural Frequency}} \\ \hline
\textbf{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 1.5}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 2}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 2.5}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 3}} \\ \hline
\textbf{Mode No} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -1.6*10\textasciicircum{}5\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -1.6*10\textasciicircum{}8\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P = \\ -1.6*10\textasciicircum{}5\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -1.6*10\textasciicircum{}8\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -1.6*10\textasciicircum{}5\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -1.6*10\textasciicircum{}8\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -1.6*10\textasciicircum{}5\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -1.6*10\textasciicircum{}8\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
1 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
2 & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase \\ \hline
3 & decrease & decrease & decrease & decrease & decrease & decrease & decrease & decrease \\ \hline
4 & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase \\ \hline
5 & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}      
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{Natural frequency change patterns of Shear beam as the number of modes increases from n = 1 to n = 5 for axial compression load = $2.4*10^5$, $2.4*10^8$ N for stiffness increment value of $10^{9}$ $\frac{N}{m}$}
\label{tab:5.235}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{} & \multicolumn{8}{c|}{\textbf{Change in Natural Frequency}} \\ \hline
\textbf{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 1.5}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 2}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 2.5}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 3}} \\ \hline
\textbf{Mode No} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -2.4*10\textasciicircum{}5\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -2.4*10\textasciicircum{}8\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -2.4*10\textasciicircum{}5\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -2.4*10\textasciicircum{}8\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P = \\ -2.4*10\textasciicircum{}5\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -2.4*10\textasciicircum{}8\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -2.4*10\textasciicircum{}5\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -2.4*10\textasciicircum{}8\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
1 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
2 & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase \\ \hline
3 & decrease & decrease & decrease & decrease & decrease & decrease & decrease & decrease \\ \hline
4 & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase \\ \hline
5 & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
            \end{landscape}
   \clearpage% Flush page
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% ksp=1e11 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\afterpage{%
    \clearpage% Flush earlier floats (otherwise order might not be correct)
   \thispagestyle{empty}% empty page style (?)
   \begin{landscape}% Landscape page
       \centering % Center table
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{Natural frequency change patterns of Shear beam as the number of modes increases from n = 1 to n = 5 for axial compression load = 0 N for stiffness increment value of $10^{11}$ $\frac{N}{m}$}
\label{tab:5.236}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{} & \multicolumn{8}{c|}{\textbf{Change in Natural Frequency}} \\ \hline
\textbf{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 1.5}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 2}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 2.5}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 3}} \\ \hline
\textbf{Mode No} & \textbf{P = 0} & \textbf{P = 0} & \textbf{P = 0} & \textbf{P = 0} & \textbf{P = 0} & \textbf{P = 0} & \textbf{P = 0} & \textbf{P = 0} \\ \hline
1 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
2 & constant & constant & constant & constant & constant & constant & constant & constant \\ \hline
3 & constant & constant & constant & constant & constant & constant & constant & constant \\ \hline
4 & constant & constant & constant & constant & constant & constant & constant & constant \\ \hline
5 & constant & constant & constant & constant & constant & constant & constant & constant \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}       
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{Natural frequency change patterns of Shear beam as the number of modes increases from n = 1 to n = 5 for axial compression load = $0.8*10^5$, $0.8*10^8$ N for stiffness increment value of $10^{11}$ $\frac{N}{m}$}
\label{tab:5.237}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{} & \multicolumn{8}{c|}{\textbf{Change in Natural Frequency}} \\ \hline
\textbf{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 1.5}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 2}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 2.5}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 3}} \\ \hline
\textbf{Mode No} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -0.8*10\textasciicircum{}5\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -0.8*10\textasciicircum{}8\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -0.8*10\textasciicircum{}5\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -0.8*10\textasciicircum{}8\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -0.8*10\textasciicircum{}5\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -0.8*10\textasciicircum{}8\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -0.8*10\textasciicircum{}5\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -0.8*10\textasciicircum{}8\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
1 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
2 & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase \\ \hline
3 & decrease & decrease & decrease & decrease & decrease & decrease & decrease & decrease \\ \hline
4 & constant & increase & constant & increase & constant & increase & constant & increase \\ \hline
5 & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}       
            \end{landscape}
   \clearpage% Flush page
}
\afterpage{%
    \clearpage% Flush earlier floats (otherwise order might not be correct)
   \thispagestyle{empty}% empty page style (?)
   \begin{landscape}% Landscape page
       \centering % Center table
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{Natural frequency change patterns of Shear beam as the number of modes increases from n = 1 to n = 5 for axial compression load = $1.6*10^5$, $1.6*10^8$ N for stiffness increment value of $10^{11}$ $\frac{N}{m}$}
\label{tab:5.238}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{} & \multicolumn{8}{c|}{\textbf{Change in Natural Frequency}} \\ \hline
\textbf{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 1.5}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 2}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 2.5}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 3}} \\ \hline
\textbf{Mode No} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -1.6*10\textasciicircum{}5\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -1.6*10\textasciicircum{}8\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P = \\ -1.6*10\textasciicircum{}5\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -1.6*10\textasciicircum{}8\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -1.6*10\textasciicircum{}5\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -1.6*10\textasciicircum{}8\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -1.6*10\textasciicircum{}5\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -1.6*10\textasciicircum{}8\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
1 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
2 & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase \\ \hline
3 & decrease & decrease & decrease & decrease & decrease & decrease & decrease & decrease \\ \hline
4 & constant & increase & constant & increase & constant & increase & constant & increase \\ \hline
5 & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}      
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{Natural frequency change patterns of Shear beam as the number of modes increases from n = 1 to n = 5 for axial compression load = $2.4*10^5$, $2.4*10^8$ N for stiffness increment value of $10^{11}$ $\frac{N}{m}$}
\label{tab:5.238}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{} & \multicolumn{8}{c|}{\textbf{Change in Natural Frequency}} \\ \hline
\textbf{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 1.5}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 2}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 2.5}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 3}} \\ \hline
\textbf{Mode No} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -2.4*10\textasciicircum{}5\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -2.4*10\textasciicircum{}8\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -2.4*10\textasciicircum{}5\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -2.4*10\textasciicircum{}8\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P = \\ -2.4*10\textasciicircum{}5\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -2.4*10\textasciicircum{}8\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -2.4*10\textasciicircum{}5\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -2.4*10\textasciicircum{}8\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
1 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
2 & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase \\ \hline
3 & decrease & decrease & decrease & decrease & decrease & decrease & decrease & decrease \\ \hline
4 & constant & increase & constant & increase & constant & increase & constant & increase \\ \hline
5 & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase & increase \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
            \end{landscape}
   \clearpage% Flush page
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% ksp=1e13 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\afterpage{%
    \clearpage% Flush earlier floats (otherwise order might not be correct)
   \thispagestyle{empty}% empty page style (?)
   \begin{landscape}% Landscape page
       \centering % Center table
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{Natural frequency change patterns of Shear beam as the number of modes increases from n = 1 to n = 5 for axial compression load = 0 N for stiffness increment value of $10^{13}$ $\frac{N}{m}$}
\label{tab:5.239}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{} & \multicolumn{8}{c|}{\textbf{Change in Natural Frequency}} \\ \hline
\textbf{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 1.5}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 2}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 2.5}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 3}} \\ \hline
\textbf{Mode No} & \textbf{P = 0} & \textbf{P = 0} & \textbf{P = 0} & \textbf{P = 0} & \textbf{P = 0} & \textbf{P = 0} & \textbf{P = 0} & \textbf{P = 0} \\ \hline
1 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
2 & constant & constant & constant & constant & constant & constant & constant & constant \\ \hline
3 & constant & constant & constant & constant & constant & constant & constant & constant \\ \hline
4 & constant & constant & constant & constant & constant & constant & constant & constant \\ \hline
5 & constant & constant & constant & constant & constant & constant & constant & constant \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}       
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{Natural frequency change patterns of Shear beam as the number of modes increases from n = 1 to n = 5 for axial compression load = $0.8*10^5$, $0.8*10^8$ N for stiffness increment value of $10^{13}$ $\frac{N}{m}$}
\label{tab:5.240}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{} & \multicolumn{8}{c|}{\textbf{Change in Natural Frequency}} \\ \hline
\textbf{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 1.5}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 2}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 2.5}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 3}} \\ \hline
\textbf{Mode No} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -0.8*10\textasciicircum{}5\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -0.8*10\textasciicircum{}8\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -0.8*10\textasciicircum{}5\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -0.8*10\textasciicircum{}8\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -0.8*10\textasciicircum{}5\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -0.8*10\textasciicircum{}8\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -0.8*10\textasciicircum{}5\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -0.8*10\textasciicircum{}8\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
1 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
2 & constant & increase & increase & increase & constant & increase & constant & increase \\ \hline
3 & constant & decrease & decrease & decrease & constant & decrease & constant & decrease \\ \hline
4 & constant & increase & constant & increase & constant & increase & constant & increase \\ \hline
5 & constant & increase & increase & increase & constant & increase & constant & increase \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}       
            \end{landscape}
   \clearpage% Flush page
}
\afterpage{%
    \clearpage% Flush earlier floats (otherwise order might not be correct)
   \thispagestyle{empty}% empty page style (?)
   \begin{landscape}% Landscape page
       \centering % Center table
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{Natural frequency change patterns of Shear beam as the number of modes increases from n = 1 to n = 5 for axial compression load = $1.6*10^5$, $1.6*10^8$ N for stiffness increment value of $10^{13}$ $\frac{N}{m}$}
\label{tab:5.241}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{} & \multicolumn{8}{c|}{\textbf{Change in Natural Frequency}} \\ \hline
\textbf{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 1.5}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 2}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 2.5}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 3}} \\ \hline
\textbf{Mode No} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -1.6*10\textasciicircum{}5\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -1.6*10\textasciicircum{}8\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P = \\ -1.6*10\textasciicircum{}5\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -1.6*10\textasciicircum{}8\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -1.6*10\textasciicircum{}5\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -1.6*10\textasciicircum{}8\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -1.6*10\textasciicircum{}5\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -1.6*10\textasciicircum{}8\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
1 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
2 & constant & increase & increase & increase & constant & increase & constant & increase \\ \hline
3 & decrease & decrease & decrease & decrease & constant & decrease & constant & decrease \\ \hline
4 & constant & increase & constant & increase & constant & increase & constant & increase \\ \hline
5 & increase & increase & constant & increase & constant & increase & constant & increase \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{Natural frequency change patterns of Shear beam as the number of modes increases from n = 1 to n = 5 for axial compression load = $2.4*10^5$, $2.4*10^8$ N for stiffness increment value of $10^{13}$ $\frac{N}{m}$}
\label{tab:5.242}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{} & \multicolumn{8}{c|}{\textbf{Change in Natural Frequency}} \\ \hline
\textbf{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 1.5}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 2}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 2.5}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{cl = 3}} \\ \hline
\textbf{Mode No} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -2.4*10\textasciicircum{}5\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -2.4*10\textasciicircum{}8\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -2.4*10\textasciicircum{}5\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -2.4*10\textasciicircum{}8\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P = \\ -2.4*10\textasciicircum{}5\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -2.4*10\textasciicircum{}8\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -2.4*10\textasciicircum{}5\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P =\\ -2.4*10\textasciicircum{}8\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
1 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
2 & increase & increase & increase & increase & constant & increase & constant & increase \\ \hline
3 & decrease & decrease & decrease & decrease & constant & decrease & decrease & decrease \\ \hline
4 & constant & increase & constant & increase & constant & increase & constant & increase \\ \hline
5 & increase & increase & constant & increase & constant & increase & increase & increase \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
            \end{landscape}
   \clearpage% Flush page
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! If you do not post a minimal code reproducing the problem, it's quite hard to help. It seems you've forgotten to match a closing brace somewhere.

Comment: you have `\afterpage{\clearpage...`  on line 123 and no matching `}`

Comment: why are you using `\afterpage` at all (I wouldn't use it for this and I wrote it)

Comment: They have said that the above code has some problems

Comment: I am using afterpage for landscape orientation

Comment: the problem is exactly as it says in the error message I copied the text to a text editor typed an extra `}` at the end and it matched the `\afterpage{`

Comment: No, you do not need afterpage to get landscape.

Comment: I think i had read either for the continuation of page nos from portrait to landscape orientation. Can you tell me whats the use of after page?

Comment: you don't need afterpage and you don't need the `\clearpage` as `landscape` does `\clearpage` already.

Comment: Thank you David!!! I will make the correction. I am still getting the same error

Comment: You can not get the same error. The error is that you have `\afterpage{\clearpage` with no matching `}` but if you delete `\afterpage{\clearpage ` you must get a different error message